# Are italics on the web bad for accessibility?

Tags: website-design, accessibility, font, formatting

On a current web project, we've received word from the client that we can no longer have any italicized text on the website we are building.

When I asked for some reasoning, I was told that "our accessibility person says it's bad for accessibility", with no other justification.

Honestly, I've never heard of this before, so I tried to do a bit of research on it.

All I've been able to find is [this post from 2007](http://shoobe01.blogspot.ca/2007/07/why-dont-we-use-italics-online-anyway.html) which literally comes to the conclusion of:

> I never found the text of any study that proves it. There's reference to one, and that's good enough for me. Instead, I am relying on the "everyone says it" method

With most of the post's references having long since rotted away.

As far as I can tell, the main reason italics were ever an accessibility issue were low dpi screens making small oblique fonts unreadable.

But in this retina world, I find it hard to believe that's still a valid reason.

**So, what are the reasons for italics being bad for accessibility, and are those reasons backed by any real studies?**

Comment: I can't see this being a legitimate argument either.

Comment: Large blocks of italic text is a problem for everyone. An occasional word or phrase is usually not a problem.

Comment: At risk of flogging an old horse, you could in any case use `<em>` and `<strong>` for emphasis on the web. If someone has difficulty with italics, that's *supposed* to be what browser settings (for example local `!important` style rules) empower them to deal with. That said, if the client "doesn't want italics" that probably means they don't want `<em>`. Explaining to them that those with accessibility issues can in theory turn off the italics that the client sees using some obscure browser settings, that may or may not be familiar to that user, probably doesn't wash ;-)

Comment: I would have +1'd if you used italics for your final sentences instead of bold text.

Comment: @mcrumley, citation?

Comment: I don't have a citation, just experience with typography. A few words of slightly more difficult text will not significantly affect overall readability. Just use it sparingly.

Comment: It's worth noting that the Chicago Manual of Style notes that using italics to emphasize certain words is the correct practice, but that specific emphasis should be kept to a bare minimum otherwise the impactfulness of said emphasis is lessened.

As for legibility, I would surmise that a lot of the readability problem with italics isn't the slant so much as the kerning of the font and the limited pixels of low ppi renderings of monitors

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Italics are a known problem for some people with dyslexia and the general advice has been to avoid italics (particularly large blocks of italic text) and instead use bold for emphasis.

[The British Dyslexia Association](http://www.bdadyslexia.org.uk/about-dyslexia/further-information/dyslexia-style-guide.html) says:

> Avoid underlining and italics: these tend to make the text appear to
>   run together. Use bold instead.

UX Movement touches on this in an article about [Bad Practices That Hurt Dyslexic Users](http://uxmovement.com/content/6-surprising-bad-practices-that-hurt-dyslexic-users/):

> Italics are sometimes used to highlight text. But you shouldn’t use
>   italicized text because they make letters hard to read. The letters
>   have a jagged line compared to non-italic fonts. The letters also lean
>   over making it hard for dyslexic users to make out the words. When
>   the text size is small, the text is even more illegible. A better
>   way to highlight is to use bold text because the letters are clearer
>   and give better contrast.

There was an [experimental study](http://blog.dyslexia.com/good-fonts-for-dyslexia-an-experimental-study/) in 2013 looking at which fonts were easiest for dyslexic individuals to read:

> Based on the evaluation of 48 dyslexic subjects ages 11-50, reading 12
>   texts with 12 different fonts, they determined that reading
>   performance was best with sans serif, monospaced, and roman fonts used
>   in the study. They also found that reading was significantly impaired
>   when italic fonts were used.

In WCAG, for [Guideline 3.1 Readable (Make text content readable and understandable)](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/meaning.html) there is an advisory technique for "Avoiding chunks of italic text".

Comment: Great answer, but I find it amusing that [the paper from the study you cite](http://dyslexiahelp.umich.edu/sites/default/files/good_fonts_for_dyslexia_study.pdf) is full of italicized text.

Comment: That second quote isn't about italics, per se, but about low resolution screens, which the OP states (and I agree) is less of an issue with mobile as well as things like cleartype. As for the last quote, while serif monospace fonts might be great for a subset, they are likely a detriment for a larger subset. I'd be wary of making decisions solely on this limited research of dyslexia.

Comment: In addition, edeverett's answer points out some other valid concerns with this particular study.

Answer (score 17):

The study list linked to in the blog mentioned by Matt Obee is here http://dyslexiahelp.umich.edu/sites/default/files/good_fonts_for_dyslexia_study.pdf

It's an interesting paper and the conclusions are worth working through:

> The main conclusion is that font types have an impact on readability of people with dyslexia.

As they do on readability with people without dyslexia. No great surprise here.

> Good fonts for people with dyslexia are Helvetic, Courier, Arial,
>   Verdana and CMU, taking into consideration both reading performance
>   and subjective preference. Also, sans serif, monospaced and roman [serif] font types
>   increase significantly the reading performance ...

Ok... so sans, mono and serif choices can work well for people with dyslexia, much they same as they can work well for people without dyslexia...

> ... while italic fonts decreased reading performance. In particular,
>   Arial It should be avoided since it significantly decreased
>   readability.

By a "decrease in reading performance" they seem to mean it took longer to read. This is to be expected with italics read by people without dyslexia. I couldn't find anything in their paper to suggest that comprehension fell when using italics. I have seen it suggested that comprehension can increase when readability goes down due to it taking more effort to read so the text is read in more detail.

It should be noted that Arial Italic is considered one of the worst designed typefaces ever to grace computers. (In fact it's not really an italic but a slanted roman sans). That crappy typefaces are hard to read is not any great surprise.

So to conclude:

1. Italics are likely to slow reading down.
2. There's nothing in the
   paper to suggest that italics are bad for accessibility.
3. Typography
   for dyslexic readers should consider the same factors as typography
   for non-dyslexic readers.

This supports the dead-horse I've been beating for a long time: **just do good typographic design and all your readers will benefit** - there is no need to have any special considerations for dyslexic readers above and beyond your non-dyslexic readers.

Comment: The article's exact conclusion is "We did not find a significant effort of _Italics_ on _Reading Time_."

Comment: @Brian But it does also note that there was an overall impact on "readability", specifically that "there was a significant effect of italics on fixation duration" (the duration was larger than the comparison) and concludes that "italic fonts decreased reading performance" and that "the reading time of the italic fonts was always worse than its roman counterpart”.

Comment: And because italics is often used to direct attention to a particular word or phrase of importance, a momentary impact to reading speed is arguably the desired outcome (for all readers). Ergo, just use italics intentionally, not gratuitously, according to the content. Don't use text effects as visual decoration.

Comment: @MattObee As edeverett says, I think the priority here should be on *comprehension*.

Comment: @belacqua I like how "comprehension" is in italics. (sorry, someone had to point that out :P)

Comment: Well put. The research in to 'best typeface for readability' are so few and far between, and those that exist relatively weak in terms of conclusions, one shouldn't put too much weight into them.

Comment: @belacqua in traditional typography, italics *isn't an effect* -- it's a type of typeface. It was carefully designed *to* be readable. Granted, computers often use a 'fake' italics (automatically slanting the typeface) which *is* an effect...but not a true italics typeface.

Comment: And also note the study studied 12 typefaces. There are thousands upon thousands of typefaces. So, it's hard to believe that the particularities of the 12 faces studies are necessarily universal truths that would apply to all typefaces.

Comment: @DA01 I don't think I'm disagreeing with you.  I'm taking your comment as clarifying, as opposed to pedantic....  (Personally I'd not claim that any conclusions are universal truths.)  Anyway, if we were able to define our terms beforehand, we'd not have the appearance of arguing, I don't think.  Your traditional typography note is appreciated, and I'm not up enough on the intent of choices made in, e.g., html5 to speak to questions re. expression versus appearance, implementation, et al. (I realize these words are overdetermined, but, comment vs. essay.)

Comment: @belacqua certainly not arguing. And defining terms is likely an ongoing challenge in the world of typography. I don't think people have agreed upon typographic terms and likely never will. They all tend to be fuzzy. :)

Comment: You make some great points here. The trouble with trying to design for people with dyslexia is that there is no 'X is good, Y is bad' that relates *purely* to dyslexia (unlike, say, colourblindless). Also, Dyslexia is quite a subjective condition. There'll be dyslexic people who are only comfortable reading dark grey text on a light grey background- something that is terrible for the larger majority of users. (Just as there are non-dyslexic people who prefer to read everything in Comic Sans. i.e. Personal preference.) So yes, makes sure the design is as comprehensible as possible *in general*.

Comment: The study proves that italicized fonts slow readers down, it states which fonts are bad for people with dyslexia, but it doesn't say to avoid proper use of italics.

The report itself makes good use of italic font which aids readability by breaking up the monotony of the text and introduces helpful emphasis.

**I contend that the study indirectly informs the use of italics: *to slow the reader and increase fixation on a particular word or passage*.** It's like having a slow motion shot in a film sequence. That's a great tool for emphasis and accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment above about creating a good typographic design and all your readers will benefit.

My problem with removing italics is that in doing so you are also ignoring the standards set out for proper document creation. Italics are to be used when referencing titles of works, foreign words/technical terms/unfamiliar words (though you can also use bold for these), names of trains, ships, aircraft, and spacecraft, and legislation. These are usually not large chunks of text. I do agree that italics should never be used simply to draw attention to a paragraph or portion of text. That also goes against good documentation standards.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Taylor. Do you have any evidence about the original poster's question of whether italics impact *accessibility*? (At the moment, your post appears to be about when italics should be used rather than how they impact legibility.)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like a question about communication than accessibility and italics along the lines of "What is the best way to respond to prescriptive feedback on designs" when what you'd prefer is feedback with more background about the suggested change. I think it's a pretty common quandary for designers in organizations where there is a product owner setting constraints.

It seems like in this instance the answer was, "go research the reason for the constraint yourself and then decide to agree"

Curious how this played out in real life?